# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, excepciones

Tengo un problema que se me genero en Android Studio, sucede que al tratar de iniciar la aplicacion que es un login en realidad que me  corria perfectamente, ahora me sale este error  y no termino de entender el porque ni como podria solucionarlo. Por cierto antes del dia de hoy todo funcionaba correctamente, y solo comenzo a salir este error el dia de hoy quisiera solucionarlo cuanto antes, leo sus respuestas:

```
   1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.6.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\89874eb5cd94db7f5e0b994c8437a305\transformed\appcompat-1.6.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: D:\acer\Documentos de Clase IDAT\CICLO 5 DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS DE LA INFORMACION\DESARROLLO DE APLICACIONES MOVILES 1 (DAM)\AGRO_EMY_APP\Agro_App\.gradle\8.0\caches\transforms-3\50dffbafee9c2d80c5f6a867c5ace569\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.4-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```